# Ajax get data only first item in while loop

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Why my ajax can get data only first item in while loop?

**Example :** First add to wishlist with first item in loop product id = 64, When I add another item product id is always 64.

**My Code :**

```
<a id='addtowishlist' class='link' href='#' data-data='".$rows['p_id']."'>Add to wishlist</a>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#addtowishlist").live('click', function(evt) {
        var link_data = $('.link').data('data');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'addtowishlist.php',
            data: ({product_id: link_data}),
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }   
        });   
    });  
});
</script>
```

Comment: use class instead of id in your html as <a class='addtowishlist' class='link' href='#' data-data='".$rows['p_id']."'>Add to wishlist</a> and change the syntax of ajax as well .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ID must be unique**. Otherwise use `class` instead. If you're using the same name for `ID`, only first matched data returned. Try following code:

This should be defined as a class *(remove id attribute)* :

```
<a class='addtowishlist link' href='#' data-data='".$rows['p_id']."'>Add to wishlist</a>
```

And this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // use class selector instead of ID
    $(".addtowishlist").live('click', function(evt) {
       // take only current clicked data element
       var link_data = $(this).data('data');
       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'addtowishlist.php',
          data: ({product_id: link_data}),
          success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
          }   
       });   
    });  
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use class instead of id in your html as

```
<a class='addtowishlist' class='link' href='#' data-data='".$rows['p_id']."'>Add to wishlist</a>
```

and change the syntax of ajax as well

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // use class selector instead of ID
    $(".addtowishlist").live('click', function(evt) {
       // take only current clicked data element
       var link_data = $(this).data('data');
       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'addtowishlist.php',
          data: ({product_id: link_data}),
          success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
          }   
       });   
    });  
});
</script>
```